# Issue in customizing plot axis in R

Tags: r, plot, axis

I realize that the fix for this problem is certainly very trivial, but I can't get my head around it for some reason!

Consider the following vector (zoo object)

```
 library(zoo)
 h1 = c(-0.0130944, -0.0132586, -0.0132235, -0.0131435, -0.0134029, -0.0128966, -0.0130439)
 h1.zoo = zoo(h1, order.by = as.Date(c("2013-12-09", "2013-12-10", "2013-12-11", "2013-12-12", "2013-12-13", "2013-12-16", "2013-12-17"))
```

I want to plot the vector h1.zoo, with a y-axis limits of -0.2 to 0. I want the y-axis intersection with the x-axis to be at y = -0.2

I have tried the following:

```
 jpeg( out.jpg, width=800, height=600 )     
 par(mai = c(1,2,1,0.7), cex=1.6, xaxs='i',yaxs='i', xpd = TRUE, width = 800, height = 600)
 if (!all( is.na(h1.zoo)))
 {
     plot( na.trim(h1.zoo), main="", xlab="Date", ylab="", yaxt = "n", bty = "n", cex.axis = 0.8)
     axis(2, las = 2, cex.axis = 0.8, at = seq(-0.02, 0, 0.002), labels = seq(-0.02, 0, 0.002), ylim = c(-0.02,0))
     title(ylab = "Contribution to Expected Return (in %)", line = 4)
 }
 dev.off()
```

but this results in a plot that has no ticks on the y-axis, and very odd proportions. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try removing the following arguments: `xpd=TRUE` and `yaxt='n'`. xpd allows to plot outside the figure region, while yaxt controls the type of y-axis.

Comment: If I do that, all it is going to do is override whatever the function axis() will do. I want to keep `yaxt = "n"` but make the function axis() work properly. To prove that, look at the limits of the y-axis are when you remove `yaxt = "n"`: they are not -0.2 and 0 as I want.

Comment: OK, what if you use `ylim-c(-0.02,0)` argument directly within the `plot()`. Then you can either get rid of `axis()` and `yaxt='n'`, or keep the `axis()` for higher axis control.

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
   plot( as.numeric(na.trim(h1.zoo)), main="", xlab="Date",
      ylab="", yaxt = "n",xaxt="n", axes = F,ylim = c(-0.02,-0.01), type = 'l')
   axis(1,pos=-0.02)
   axis(2,pos=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind

[image]

Code: (using data provided)

```
par(mai = c(1,2,1,0.7), xaxs='i',yaxs='i', xpd = F)
plot( na.trim(h1.zoo), main="", xlab="Date", ylab="", yaxt = "n", bty = "n", cex.axis = 0.6, ylim=c(-0.0135,-0.0128))
axis(2, las = 2, cex.axis = 0.6, at = seq(-.014,-.012,.0001))
title(ylab = "Contribution to Expected Return (in %)", line = 3)
```

There are several things going on here.

First, you need to specify `ylim=` in the plot command, or `plot(...)` will default to the max and min values of the data. In your case that was `(-0.0134,-0.0129)`. Then, when you specified axis ticks ranging from `-0.02 to 0` in increments of 0.002, `axis(...)` applies this to the range set implicitly in `plot(...)`. But there are no tick marks in that range.

Second, you need to set `xpd=F` to clip the axis properly.

Third, there are no width and length arguments to `par(...)`.